# What is the number of processes generated by forks in this code

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main(void) {
  pid_t a,b,c;
  a=fork();
  b=fork();
  if(a||b)
    c=fork();
  printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b,c);
}
```

So I changed this code like this, originally, it was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main(void) {
  if(fork()||fork())
    fork();
  return 0;
}
```

So by that printf, I would have 5 processes, but is it correct or is it a better way to check the number of processes? Like, printing all rows and getting only the ones with 0 and some other values, after all the forks, is what I did

Comment: You need to initialize `c`, because it won't be assigned in the original parent process.

Comment: uhm, can you tell me how to do that, I don't quite understand

Comment: The print line will print `c=0` in the processes generated by the last `fork()`.

Comment: Add an initial value: `pid_t a,b,c = 0;`

Comment: Actually, I misread what you were doing. c = fork()` does execute in the parent process. It won't be executed in either of the forked processes.

Comment: So, is it correct like this?

Comment: Are you asking if the two versions create the same number of child processes?

Comment: Oh, they don't? So how would I write code for the second one to get the number of processes? the second is important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not equivalent because of the short-circuiting of the `||` operator.

In the first version,

```
b = fork();
```

executes unconditionally in both the parent and the first child. So at this point there are two child processes and a grandchild process.

In the second version,

```
if (fork() || fork())
```

creates one child, and then creates a second child only in the original parent process. It doesn't create a grandchild process because the first `fork()` returns `0` in the child process, so the second `fork()` is skipped.

I don't think there's a way to make the two equivalent without variables.

Comment: So the second version makes 2 processes?

Comment: It created 4 processes. 2 child processes and 2 grandchild processes.

Comment: The first version also creates a great-grandchild process.